# Can you document the APIs which are developed by someone else using swagger?

Tags: javascript, java, api, swagger, swagger-ui

I am a newbie to swagger.io. And i have a bunch of APIs that have been developed by a team which is no longer working with me. So these APIs aren't properly documented by them. So, i was thinking to use swagger and document them properly.

But the Question is, Is possible to document these APIs with swagger?

If yes, How? 
If no, is there any other tool/framework for me to do it?

Comment: Do you have access to the source?

Comment: No, I don't have access to the source.

Comment: Then you cant document the API's with Swagger, at least with Java. Swagger works by placing Java annotations of the methods and fields you want to document.  If you dont have the source, you obviously cannot do this.  I am not sure how Swagger works with JS, but I imagine its probably similar.

Comment: Thank you but is there any other tool/framework which can do that without the access to source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can write an OpenAPI (fka Swagger) definition (.yaml or .json) for an API manually in the [Swagger Editor](http://editor.swagger.io) and then use Swagger UI to display the API docs. However, in this case the OpenAPI definition is not synchronized with the API implementation (that is, not linked to the source code), so if the implementation changes you will need to update the OpenAPI definition manually.

Answer (score -1):

Not swagger, but WireMock will let observe and record an API as a black box.

http://wiremock.org/docs/record-playback/